# prove that $MQ= MQ'$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

> In the above figure, ABC is an acute triangle, M is the midpoint of AB, H is the orthocenter of ABC, and D,E,F are the altitudes of ABC. P and Q are the intersections of the circumcircle of AHB with the circumcircle of DEF (which is the nine-point circle of ABC) so that P is on the left side of line CH. Q' is on the line MQ and the circumcircle of ABC. R is the intersection of ED, PH, and MQ (which is well-defined although the problem doesn't require using point R). The question is to prove that MQ = MQ'.

Let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be the circumcircles of triangles ABC and AHB respectively. Note that both of these circles have the same radius (e.g. by the extended law of sines and the fact that $EDCH$ is a cyclic quadrilateral).  I know $\omega_1$ is  a downward translation of $\omega_2$ another and that $\angle A Q'B = \angle AQB < 180\circ$ , but I'm not sure how to prove the two lengths MQ and MQ' are equal. I'm not sure if Q' is the reflection of H under line AB. Also I'm not sure if triangles AQ' B and AHB are congruent. But to prove the congruency, I'd need to prove $\angle Q'AB = \angle HAB$ or that there's some other shared angle or side between the two triangles.

Comment: I've seen that you've barely accepted/upvoted any of the answers given to your newest questions. It's often nice to get some feedback after the effort one invests in answering. Does my answer address your question, or is there something I've missed? Please, do not hesitate to ask if something was unclear :D

Answer (score 2):

Notice that, in order to prove that $MQ=MQ'$, you do neither need any of $E,D,F, P,R$ nor the nine point circle. You can even generalize as follows:

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle with orthocenter $H$ and denote by $M$ the midpoint of $AB$. Let $Q$ be a point on the arc $AB$ of the circle $\odot ABH$ and let $Q'$ be the intersection of $MQ$ and the arc $BA$ of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. Show that $MQ=MQ'$.

Observe that $\angle AHB = 180^\circ-((90^\circ-A)+(90^\circ- B))= A+B=180^\circ - C= \angle BQ'A$. We will prove the result defining the phantom point $Q''$ which results by reflecting $Q$ on $M$, i.e. $\overrightarrow{QQ''}=2\overrightarrow{QM}$. But then, $M$ is both the midpoint of $AB$ and $QQ''$, so $AQ''BQ$ is a parallelogram. Hence, $\angle BQ''A=\angle AQB = \angle AHB = \angle BQ'A$. Since both $Q'$ and $Q''$ lie on the ray $\overrightarrow{QM}$ and define the same angle over $AB$, we conclude $Q'=Q''$, and therefore: $MQ = MQ'' = MQ'$.